# c# Find element/s with a specific child element

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

[Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-find-an-element-with-a-specific-child-element)

The sample code finds the attribute names of the elements whose children elements'values match the value entered in a texbox

Now look at my code and XMLfile and you'll see that they're identical to the above link. The problem is that my code only prints the first group that matches the text box value.

```
XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<groups>
  <group name="a">
    <ip>10.3.4</ip>
    <ip>10.1.4</ip>
  </group>
  <group name="b">
    <ip>10.2.1</ip>
    <ip>10.3.4</ip>
    <ip>10.55.55</ip>
  </group>
 </groups>
```

Code

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("c:\etc);
IEnumerable<XElement> tests =
   from el in root.Elements("group")
   where (string)el.Element("ip") == textBox1.Text
   select el;

foreach (XElement el in tests)
   Console.WriteLine((string)el.Attribute("name"));
```

The problem is in the where clause. Because if i comment it, the system will print both group names but when the where clause is active, it's always only returning 1 group. might as well be using FirstOrDefault() -_-

Comment: what is value of `textBox1.Text`?

Comment: format is 2digit#.2digit#.2digit#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tests =
    from el in root.Elements("group")
    where el.Elements("ip").Any(o => o.Value == textBox1.Text)
    select el;
```

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted. thank you for the code. it works. i did vote but my rep is low so it wont show sorry

Comment: @Leo if this is your accepted answer, then you should accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(@"your path to a file");
//set text box to some default value to test if function will work
textBox1.Text = "10.1.4";
//here I used etension method, commented is alternative version, for better understanding
IEnumerable<XElement> tests = root.Elements("group").Where(gr => gr.Elements("ip").Any(ip => ip.Value == textBox1.Text));
//IEnumerable<XElement> tests = root.Elements("group").Where(gr => gr.Elements("ip").Where(ip => ip.Value == textBox1.Text).Count() > 0);
foreach (XElement el in tests)
    //Console.WriteLine((string)el.Attribute("name"));
    MessageBox.Show((string)el.Attribute("name"));
```

Your code didn't work, as you compared single element against the text of a text box. What you want is to check if any among the `ip` elements is equal to specified text.

Comment: please explain. i copied the sample code (i pasted the link at the top of my post). sample worked but my version didn't even though both had the same goal

Comment: I explained why your code didn't work. You have also solution below, which uses LINQ. You also have my answer, which solves problem with LINQ extension methods.

Comment: yes you explained why it didn't work and he wrote the missing portion of the where clause. what i don't understand is why the single comparison in the sample link i posted worked whereas mine didn't. i will revise both versions again

Comment: @Leo In the example, single node is compared, you have two nodes to compare, thus difference.

Answer (score 0):

In both groups you have the same ip

```
<ip> 10.3.4 </ ip>
```

In this case it will even bring both groups together.

I'd advise doing one more condition by checking the 'name'.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
// a, b
string[] matchingNames = xml.Root.Elements("group")
    .Where(g => g.Elements("ip").Any(e => e.Value == textBoxText))
    .Select(g => g.Attribute("name").Value).ToArray();
```

Select the attribute name from groups where any of the child ip elements contain the text box text.